# Infrastructure for a "news-feed"

Tags: python, facebook, pylons, infrastructure, feed

I'd like to offer a news-feed like feature for users of our website.  When the user logs in, he is shown a list of the latest updates across various areas of the site.

I'm afraid that this is going to be difficult to scale.

What are some networking / database topologies that can support a scalable infrastructure without having lots of copies of the same data?  (I'd like to make it so if a piece of data is updated, each user's feed is also updated live).

Thanks for the assistance and advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't prematurely optimize.
2. This might be more of a question for [the Server Fault crowd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scalability).
3. Performance at scale often *requires* having lots of copies of the same data - you tagged the question "facebook," and that's part of how Facebook does it.  Twitter, too.  You are asking for a system that's fast ("updated live"), cheap ("without having lots of copies of the same data") and good (does the previous two correctly).  **Pick two.**